# Fold function does not produce expected result

Tags: f#, fold

The following fold function loads duplicate players into the bases record:

```
    (initializedBase, plays) ||> List.fold (fun bases play -> 
                                                Some play.Player |> move bases)
```

The test is the following:

```
[<Test>]
let ``2 players each hit single``() =
    // Setup
    let players = [{ Player= Scott; Hit= Single }; { Player= Brian; Hit= Single }]

    // Test
    let bases = players |> assignBases

    bases |> should equal { First=Some Brian; Second=Some Scott; Third=None }
```

The actual result is:

```
{ First=Some Scott; Second=Some Scott; Third=None }
```

I expected:

```
{ First=Some Brian; Second=Some Scott; Third=None }
```

The entire code is here:

```
module Foo

(*Types*)
type Position =
    | First
    | Second
    | Third 

type Player =
    | Scott
    | Brian
    | Cherice

type Hit =
    | Single
    | Double
    | Triple

type Play = { Player: Player; Hit: Hit }

type Bases = { 
    First:Player  option
    Second:Player option
    Third:Player  option
}

(*Functions*)
let assignBases (plays:Play list) =

    let initializedBase = { First=None; Second=None; Third=None }

    let move bases player =

        match bases with
        | { First= None;   Second=None;   Third=None }   -> { bases with First=player }
        | { First= player; Second=None;   Third=None }   -> { bases with First=player; Second=bases.First }
        | { First= None;   Second=player; Third=None }   -> { bases with First=None; Second=None; Third=player }
        | { First= None;   Second=None;   Third=player } -> { bases with First=player }
        | _ -> initializedBase // fill the rest out later...

    (initializedBase, plays) ||> List.fold (fun bases play -> 
                                                Some play.Player |> move bases)

(*Tests*)
open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit

[<Test>]
let ``2 players each hit single``() =
    // Setup
    let players = [{ Player= Scott; Hit= Single }; { Player= Brian; Hit= Single }]

    // Test
    let bases = players |> assignBases

    bases |> should equal { First=Some Brian; Second=Some Scott; Third=None }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the problem has anything to do with `Seq.fold` as such. If I'm not mistaken, the error is in the second line of the match expression in the `move` function:

```
| { First=player; Second=None; Third=None } -> { bases with First=player; Second=bases.First }
```

The pattern uses `player` to capture the value of the `First` field of `bases`. Although it may seem like it should, this does **not** match that to the value of `player` from outside the match expression! If you needed that, you would need to use a `when` clause additionally.

As it is, from the moment F# determines that second case is the correct one (which will be `Second` and `Third` being `None` and `First` having a `Some` value), until control leaves the *whole* match expression, the name `player` denotes a new binding and is said to be "shadowing" the old `player` value.

Thus, when you assign `player` to `First` in the result part of that match case, that will again be the original value of `bases.First` - the same that you then set for `Second`.

So what you want that second match case to be is

```
| { First=oldFirst; Second=None; Third=None } -> { bases with First=player; Second=oldFirst }
```

Now, `player` still refers to the same value as outside the match expression, which is the one you want to enter the field at `First`, and `Second` gets the player you "picked up" from `First`.